# Twitter app with custom notification list?

Tags: android, twitter

Is there a Twitter app for Android that notifies on every tweet, but only from certain people you are following? For example:

- Either lets you manually select favorite people, or makes use of Twitter's     Lists feature to only show notifications from people in a specific list
- Notifications of tweets from those people pop-up on the screen or status bar regardless of what app you are using (like many text messaging apps)
- By default doesn't notify on tweets from everyone you follow (so it should be **opt-in, not opt-out**)
- Does not need any kind of tweet or reply feature

Basically I'm following a lot of people on Twitter but want to get pop-up notifications on my phone when *select* individuals post something, without having to unfollow everyone else. The various apps I've tried so far either show tweets from everyone by default or only notify on DM/mentions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **TweetCaster** app for Android has a **Custom Notifications** option which I think is exactly what you are looking for. A notification will be given for any users you choose to put in the Custom Notification list when they tweet.

**To enable:** From settings go to **Notifications**. The first thing you'll want to do is make sure **"Background notifications" is enabled**, and **disable "Notify on new tweets"**. (otherwise you'd always be notified, making the custom list meaningless) Then at the very bottom you'll find **Custom Notifications**.

[image]

Tapping **Add Custom Notification** gives you a list of the users you're following. Selecting any user immediately adds them to the Custom Notifications list.

**Add Custom Notification** will be *at the bottom of the list* once you've already added users.
[image]

Keep in mind that this doesn't honor any Smart Filter settings, doesn't make use of your lists, and notifies on all tweets from the selected users, including re-tweets and replies. Clicking on a notification will hide it and launch TweetCaster, but may or may not actually go to that tweet's details in the app.

Play Store link:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handmark.tweetcaster

Comment: Thanks I hope you don't mind me editing some instructions in. TweetCaster is not very intuitive and has some problems but it meets most of my requirements.

Comment: Great! Don't mind at all, I approved the edit now.